# Performance: NaCl vs Emscripten

Tags: javascript, c++, llvm, google-nativeclient, emscripten

How does Google's [native client](https://developer.chrome.com/native-client/nacl-and-pnacl) (both NaCl and PNaCl) compare to [Emscripten](http://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/) in ported C++ code performance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way to find out is to port something and profile. I have done work with both systems, porting CPU-intensive C/C++ libraries to both NaCl and JS-via-Emscripten. I have found both to be remarkably performant. Not exactly the same as compiled C/C++, but fast enough that they can accomplish their tasks in real-time.